# Excel formula gives error - 'You entered too many arguments' - IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I have a tier pricing
first 10 units @ $100
next 15 units @ $50
and any further units @$25

For example for 7 units the cost is $700. For 11 = $1050 and for 30 it should be $1875

I tried to put the following formula but i get an error of too many arguments.

`=IF(P10<10,(P10*100),IF(P10>10<26,10*100+P10-10*50),if(P10>26,10*100+15*50+((P10-25)*25)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF` function only accepts a maximum of 3 arguments. The error occurred because you closed the bracket after this `IF(P10>10<26,10*100+P10-10*50)`. Thus having 4 arguments.  The bracket must be removed. Then, you must insert it at the end of your formula.

You also have another problem with your formula: `P10>10<26`. If you are trying to compare when P10 is greater than 10 and less than 26, you should use `AND(P10>10,P10<26)`.

Comment: Sorry i am a novice. i tried updating it and reducing the calculations. But still if i tried to add the third if statement i get the same error.  Till here it is fine, now i just want to add the one for greater than 25 units                  =IF(P10<10,(P10*100),IF(P10<26,P10-10*50+1000))

Comment: @Kirk It should be something like this: `IF(P10<10,(P10*100),IF(P10<26,P10-10*50+1000,IF(P10>25,P10*50)))`. Replace the last calculation with yours.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works out. I just had to tweak it by adding the brackets for my subtraction. Here is the final formula that worked.  =IF(P10<10,(P10*100),IF(P10<26,(P10-10)*50+1000,IF(P10>25,(P10-25)*25+1750)))

Answer (score 0):

How about building a pricing table and then using =VLOOKUP to calculate? Below is an example:

[image]

Comment: Sorry it wont solve my problem as the pricing is a scale. So for 21 units i would charge 10x100 + 10x75 + 1 x 50  (using your table above)

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula to:

```
=IF(P10<10,(P10*100),IF(AND(P10>10,P10<26),10*100+P10-10*50,IF(P10>26,10*100+15*50+((P10-25)*25))))
```